# Can I prevent an interface from being implemented?

Tags: java, oop

I have the following Situation:

```
public interface A {
    void doSomethingCool();
}

public interface B extends A {
    void doSomethingVeryBCool();
}
public interface C extends A {
    void doSomethingVeryCCool();
}
```

In my application I can only use classes implementing B or C. But there are parts of the code, where I want to use "a.doSomethingCool()", because I don't know (and don't care) which implementation is used.

Can I enforce, that there are only implementations of B and C? 
Or prevent the interface A from being implemented?

Comment: I don't think you can; I don't think you should want to.  You may be able to do something clever at runtime using aspects, but if I were a client of your library I'd be unhappy to have my choices restricted.  The best you can do is documentation.

Comment: no you can not...

Comment: If you wanted to obtain something similar. you could make A an abstract class and throw an Exception indicating the dire consequences of extending directly from "A". Make them scary though, because people otherwise will simply catch the exception and ignore your warnings. Apart from that, consider changing your design.

Comment: @Exception_al yes interfaces extend other interfaces

Comment: Question is, why would you want to do that? If you can apply something on B because B is-a A and on C because C is-a A, then why would you not be able to do it on D, if D inherits from A? I'd rather introduce something like bool validForThisAndThat(); in A which is required for those actions, is false in A and true in B and C, and if somebody says that he implements a D which returns true for that, then well, it's his responsibility to make sure that this works out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot directly enforce the interface not being implemented, however you can make the interface package-local:

```
interface A {...} //no public
```

This way classes outside that package cannot see the interface.

EDIT: however, this does mean that you cannot do something like

```
A a = getA();
```

outside the package because A cannot be resolved.

Comment: You are a genius! It's SO simple! This actually prevents the use of "class Foo implements A" 
I would have never thought, that an interface can be package-protected. Thank you!